# How to Upgrade NetBeans IDE from 6.9 to 6.9.1

Tags: windows-xp, netbeans

I have NetBeans IDE 6.9 installed on my Windows XP machine. If I use `Help -> Check for Updates` it doesn't detect a new version, but the [NetBeans web site](http://netbeans.org/index.html) lists 6.9.1 as the latest release.

I downloaded the 6.9.1 installer, but if I try to select the same folder as my existing install for the destination it won't allow me, telling me the folder isn't empty.

The FAQ [gives an example](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUpgradeInstallation) of an upgrade that can't be accomplished, but shows a major release version difference, not a minor one.

Comment: This is an annoyance I also have, that netbeans does not do nice incremental upgrades like firefox/chrome browsers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work-around, I installed to the versioned (6.9.1) folder. The new installation picked up all my projects from the previous one.